# jQuery Sortable not working with twitter Embedded Tweets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter, jquery-ui-sortable

I am sorting the div with help of `jQuery Sortable`. this is perfectly working,
but when I drag a div (which contain the embedded content of `tweets` ) and drop anywhere, it gets removed from the `DOM`, actually after the drop `tweets block` `iframe` is remove from console.

**Here is my Script**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        update: function (event, ui) {

                $('.storymode').each(function () {
                //get the order of div after sort
                var order = $(this).sortable("toArray", {attribute: 'rowdropid'}).toString();

                        $.ajax({
                        // ajax request  for saving sortable div in DB
                            ....
                            ....
                        });
                });
                },
    });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML code**

```
    <div id="sortable">
<div>
            <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" align="center"><a href="https://twitter.com/CrazyDogTShirts/status/611263713673392128"></a></blockquote>
        </div>
</div>
```

**Script For twitter**

```
    !function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
        if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = p + '//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }
    }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');

</script>
```

see the demo example here http://dothejob.in/tw.php

please suggest me the correct way that how to sort or drag-drop the iframe content

Comment: Your embedded tweets are inside of an iframe. You can't apply any styles or add any javascript to whatever is inside of that embedded code. This means that you can't make the tweets sortable.

If you still want to make this happen you have to find a way to embed your tweets into your webpage, not an iframe. Not on Twitter myself but maybe an API or different embed method?

Answer (score 0):

Your embedded tweets are inside of an iframe. You can't apply any styles or add any javascript to whatever is inside of that embedded code. This means that you can't make the tweets sortable.

If you still want to make this happen you have to find a way to embed your tweets into your webpage, not an iframe. Not on Twitter myself but maybe an API or different embed method?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, one potentially viable approach would be to delete/create rather than move. You can use our factory functions to dynamically create a timeline widget.

More from twitter developer's forum: 
https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-widget-break-when-moved-with-jquery/65839